# I have php 5 configured on apache 2.4, yet simple echo hangs the response

Tags: php, apache

This one has me stumped.  I've set up Apache and PHP to run and even can get a simple phpinfo to render fine:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

works great, but when I try:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello...';
?>
```

Get a 101 error, no response.  Does anyone know why the echo would cause this?

Comment: you probably want to add the output of your apache and php error files. just seeing these spare informations is like guessing

Comment: Sorry Criss, I figured out the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, it seems I had an instance of Tomcat running on the same machine.  I can't think of how that would cause the echo to fail on that server instance, but once I ditched Tomcat all was good.